# Get data from parent component to child component without @Input

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get data from parent component to child component without using @Input?

I don't want to use @Input because I have to use the child selector (< app-child >) in the parent html, that way it will also display the child component template and the only thing I need is dataParent = [1,2,3] (sample data).

I tried with service method but it didn't work, when I navigate through a button from parent to child, I don't get dataParent in my child component.

my folders:

-parent-component -> pie-component -> child-component

The main page is parent component, he displays the pie component with his selector in his html (< app-pie >) and when I click on the pie, I navigate to child component

Here my code with Service method :

data-from-pie.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataFromPieService {
  private dataParent: [] = [];
  public data$ = this.dataParent;

  setData(data: []) {
    this.dataParent = data;
  }
  getData(): [] {
    return this.dataParent;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

pie-chart-component.ts :

```
dataParent = [1,2,3,4]

public pieChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    onClick: () => {
      this.getPieData();
}
getPieData() {
      this.dataFromPie.setData(this.dataParent);
      this.router.navigate(['/child']);
}
```

child-component :

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  dataFromParent: [] =[];

  constructor(private dataFromPie: DataFromPieService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataFromParent = this.dataFromPie.getData();
    console.log('my data from parent', this.dataFromParent)
  }

}
```

When I go to child component through the onClick on the pie, I don't have any log, but when I go back to parent component with the previous button on the browser I have the log (I want the log on child component).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Input from parent-component to pie-component and then send the same data in child-component.

Comment: I can through this way, but (correct me If it's false) to send data with @Input , you have to call the child component with his selector <app-child> in the pie-component.html and I don't want to display child template in the pie template but as a single page alone and get data from pie component

Comment: Correct, you have to use the selector to use input. If you want to send data without using Input then you have to use subject or behaviour subject to send data. Just pss the data with next handler and you'll get data after subscribing in that desired  component @SS.h777